# Adding a refresh header keeps the URL in the address bar static

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, http-headers

I have an intranet application that I'm reworking security on.

Basically we have to time the user out if they just leave their browser open for a certain amount of time.

Adding this code I found anywhere on the page (I'm putting it in my common header file) does the trick:

```
Response.AddHeader "Refresh", CStr(CInt(Session.Timeout + 1) * 60)
```

This will refresh the page one minute after the session times out where the code on the page redirects the user back to the login page.

Problem is that now the URL in the address bar doesn't change.

For example, if they timeout on the page intranet.com/you/are/here, any navigation after the timeout will always show that URL.

What am I missing here?  Do I have to add an additional header?

Thanks.

Comment: What code are you using to redirect them elsewhere?

Comment: The code varies from app to app as there are some older ASP apps mixed in with newer ones.  Basically every page has something like this `If Not Session("app.user") Then Response.Redirect "/?timeout=true"`

Comment: Just seems to me that the redirecting part itself is likely to blame as the header your doing simply adds a refresh.

Comment: You're right, it seems to be working fine now, I must have done something wrong earlier and fixed it indadvertedly.  Thanks.